# How should I reorganize this deployment?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, capacity-planning

I am the de facto IT guy for a small (20-ish employees) law firm (this is not my primary responsibility). I have no coding experience, though I have been researching SharePoint for months trying to learn it. We use SharePoint Online purely as a document management system. It was set up before I was hired.

It is only used for internal purposes, no outside

Our organization is as follows:

- 1 Site collection
- Over 2,000 sites, one for every client, each with libraries in it.

People use Word and Outlook heavily, and Excel for timekeeping, but we don't use any other features of SharePoint or Office 365. It feels like we are paddling a sailboat - there must be a better way to work. People do things like share an Outlook Tasks list and use it as a central location for updates, where each Task refers to a project, and they simply edit the task description to share updates on the project.

**How can I try to reorganize it?**

To keep with the water metaphor, I'm up the creek without a paddle at this point, and I just don't know where to start. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is purely depend upon the organization requirements. What kind of features they want to use.

- you can re-brand the site
- rather creating the indiviual site for each client, you can creat a document library where you can store documents for all client. but use some workflow to tag / ID the item with client ID. CLientName+DOCID
- create different libraries for different things i.e policies, laws and regulation etc
- you can also think of using the BI services.